# Unable to pass variables with custom components in knockout 3.2

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-components

I am trying to move forward with custom components in knockout 3.2. Everything works nice if I am using predefined parameters. For example is this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbny6r2f/1/).

But when I pass parameters from my view model (I have read how to do it [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html)) I am not getting anything: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbny6r2f/3/). What am I doing wrong?

Here is my js code:

```
ko.components.register('pagination', {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        var self = this;
        this.page = ko.observable(params.page);
        this.max = ko.observable(params.max);

        this.list = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            var a = self.page(),
                list = [],
                min = a - 2 < 1 ? 1 : a - 2,
                max = a + 2 > self.max() ? self.max() : a + 2;

            for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
                list.push(i);
            }
            return ko.observableArray(list);
        });

        this.callback = function (i) {
            console.log(i);
            self.page(i);
        };
    },
    template: {
        element: 'pagination-tpl'
    }
});

function Vm(){
    this.page = ko.observable(2);
    this.max = ko.observable(6);
}
var vm = new Vm();

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('koBinding_somePage'));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [linked article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html) explains this behavior int he **How params are passed to the component** section:

> If a parameter creates dependencies itself (accesses the value of an observable or computed), then **the component will receive a computed that returns the value**.

So in your case the `params.page` and the `params.max` contain a computed observable property and not the value.

So you just need to assign them to your local fields:

```
viewModel: function (params) {
       var self = this;
       this.page = params.page;
       this.max = params.max;
       //...
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v45nmznz/).